# Receiving push notification in iOS when the app is closed using GCM

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My app receives push notifications using GCM. My android app works perfectly in that when i completely close the app i still receive notifications however if i do the same with my iOS version i don't receive anything.

Note this will of course be after the app has registered for the first time and then the app is closed. I cant find much information about this. some posts are saying you cant do it. but the likes of facebook and facebook messenger all do it. Does anyone know how this is done?

this is my

```
DidReceiveRemoteNotification method which is taken from the GCM documentation

// [START ack_message_reception]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Handle the received message
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_messageKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler 
{
    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Handle the received message
    // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_messageKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END ack_message_reception]
```

my payload sent looks like this

```
$payload =  array('registration_ids' => $Regids,
                  'content_available' => false,
                  'notification' => array("body"=> $_POST['message'],
                                          "sound" => "default",
                                          'badge' => '1'
                                          )
                  );
```

note this works if the app is in the background

Comment: please comment the down vote, this is a valid question

Comment: I'm not the down vote.... but I would assume that you have been down voted because you haven't provided any details about what you are currently doing (i.e. code, and push content, as well as iOS version).

Comment: fair point :-) i have added more info

Comment: Great - sufficiently detailed now for me to up-vote your question, and also the relevant answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get this working by adding this to my pay load

```
"priority" => "high"
```

maybe someone can comment why this worked as i have no idea

Answer (score 2):

It also does work with iOS when the app is closed - if it doesn't, something is wrong.

However, you cannot use **silent pushes** with iOS when the app was closed by the user (up-swipe in task switcher) - so if your app wants to react on a push without the user having to tap on it, you can't do that when the app was closed.

Comment: awesome, at least i know the issue is with my code then and not that it cant be done. I will update the question when i find the issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I Think you are not specifying the `alert` key in the notification payload. The message provided in the `alert` key of the notification payload will be displayed on the device when the app is closed.

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

In the above payload check the `alert` key. The Message **Message received from Bob** will be displayed in the notification center of the iPhone when the app is closed.

Comment: i think you are absolutely correct, i am using notification instead with body

Comment: @Rob85 Try this way, and if it works please up vote the answer.

Comment: Try this
`$payload =  array('registration_ids' => $Regids,
                  'content_available' => false, 
                  'alert' = $_POST['message'],
                  'notification' => array("body"=> $_POST['message'],
                                          "sound" => "default",
                                          'badge' => '1'
                                          )
                  );`

Comment: that doesnt seem to have worked, i still get a success that it was sent but nothing comes up

Comment: @Rob85 Whether its coming when the app is open?

Comment: no it works with app in the back ground, nothing happens if the app is foreground though and nothing happens if it is completely closed

Comment: @Rob85 This will not pop up when the app is in foreground. For that u have to write code to do so in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: yeah i realise that, i am not bothered about the foreground part, its the receiving when closed that is the most important to me.

Comment: still at a loss here, are there any settings in the app to make it work when off. for example for background you need to set the background mode up

Comment: could the content_available have something to do with it. if i switch this to true then i get nothing at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97208/discussion-between-arif-vadkey-and-rob85).